# How to read OTP automatically sent by twitter digits in react-native

Tags: android, ios, twitter, react-native, twitter-fabric

I had implemented digits in react-native app using this npm package **JeanLebrument/react-native-fabric-digits**

Here is a link:
https://github.com/JeanLebrument/react-native-fabric-digits

It is working fine, but i don't know how to automatic reading OTP send by twitter in my react-native app.

Any one have idea or implemented automatic read digits OTP?

**UPDATE:**
I find solution for android:
By adding

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```

to AndroidManifest.xml, it is now automatically reading OTP.

But i didn't find solution in ios yet, It is possible in ios or not?

Answer (score -1):

```
I had work on this. I use these technique to implement it.
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20901982/5349267

Comment: question is in react native~